# Allocating space for an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a C++ program that dynamically allocates an array of integers. In the final function below I can't figure out how to allocate space for the array, `new int[*arrPtr];` is what I had in mind after reading the chapter on pointers, and it compiles properly, but the program crashes. Could anyone take a look at my code and point me in the right direction?

I greatly appreciate any assistance on this matter, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: int * arrPtr = nullptr; *arrPtr tries to take the contents of memory at address 0x0 and interpret it as an integer.   This memory doesn't belong to your program and the OS kills your program for trying to use invalid memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not

```
new int[*arrPtr]
```

It's

```
arrPtr = new int[num]; //num is the size of the array.
```

Comment: ..or just use a std::vector

Comment: @xaxxon I agree that vectors are a lot nicer to play with, but the line 'using namespace std;' leads me to believe that this is a classroom exercise regarding pointers.

Comment: or it could simply be for simplicity of the test case.  Don't judge based on the syntax of the test case - remember, it's supposed to be stripped down as much as possible.